# How to use curl multipart form data to post array field from command line ?

Tags: curl, terminal

Using curl request

```
curl -v -X PATCH -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Auth-token:abcde" -F "first_name=snme" -F 'tags[]=chec' -F 'tags[]=chec2' http://example.com/api/users/1
```

I want to post tags as an array. So parsing the request i should get `tags = ['check' , 'check2']`  etc.

What I get now is `{"tags[]" = "chec"}`

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
   curl -X POST -d 'tags[]=check&tags[]=check2' 'http://example.com/api/users/1' -v
```

For multipart it should work with what you have tried:

```
   curl -X POST -F 'tags[]=check1' -F 'tags[]=check2' 'http://example.com/api/users/1' -v
```

Returns:

```
    {"tags":["chec","chec2"], ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

For some server, you can use

`curl -X POST -F 'tags=check1' -F 'tags=check2' 'http://example.com/api/users/1' -v`

Answer (score -1):

For me on BASH is work like this:

> curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F
>   "email="$EMAIL""
>   https://slack.com/api/users.admin.invite?token=$TOKEN&t=$DATE&first_name=$F1&last_name=$F2